# console.log and redirect in node.js doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I make application to register and login, but something is not working properly

this is users.js from routers/users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});

var User = require('../models/user');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', {
    'title': 'Register'
  });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', {
    'title': 'Login'
  });
});

router.post('/register', upload.single('profileimage'), function(req, res, next){
  //get form values
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 = req.body.password2;

//check for image field
  if(req.files && req.files.profileimage){
    console.log('Uploading File...');
    //var profileimage = req.file.filename;

  //file info
    var profileImageOriginalName = req.files.profileimage.originalname;

    var profileImageName         = req.files.profileimage.name;
    var profileImageMime         = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
    var profileImagePath         = req.files.profileimage.path;
    var profileImageExt          = req.files.profileimage.extension;
    var profileImageSize         = req.files.profileimage.size;
  } else {
  //set a default image
    var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';
  }

//form validation
  req.checkBody('name','Name field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email','Email field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email','Email not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('username','Username field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password','Password field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

  //check for errors
  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if(errors){
    res.render('register', {
      errors: errors,
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      password2: password2
    });
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      profileimage: profileImageName
    });

    //create user
    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(user);
    });

    //success message
    req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and may log in');

    res.location('/');
    res.redirect('/');
  }

});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done){
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        console.log('Unknown User');
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
      }
    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(isMatch){
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        console.log('Invalid Password');
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Password'});
      }
    });
  });
}
));

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect: '/users/login', failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'}), function(req, res){
  console.log('Authentication Successful');
  req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

and this is user.js from models/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeauth');
var db = mongoose.connection;

//user schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    index:true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    bcrypt: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  profileimage: {
    type: String
  }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
    if(err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
  User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
  var query = {username: username};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
  bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, 10, function(err, hash){
    if(err) throw err;
    //set hashed pw
    newUser.password = hash;
    //create user
    newUser.save(callback);
  });
}
```

When using a registration, it works, however, when using the login does not work. Concretely does not show me in cmd whether I was right or not logs, and the redirect function does not work.

[comand prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMJRK.jpg)

Comment: I think it server script, browser can't capture it, Check in cmd console :)

Comment: I know that, here's what I displayed when I log http://i.stack.imgur.com/WMJRK.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had a quick look to `passport` docs and it looks like your authentication fails and you get redirected to the url that is specified in `failureRedirect` prop of `passport.authenticate` method.

By default `passport.authenticate` works so, that if authentication fails, *passport* will respond with a `401 Unauthorized` status, and any additional route handlers will not be invoked. Since you have specified some options to the method, in particular, an url where to redirect, *passport* does the redirection instead of responding `401 Unauthorized`. That is shown on the provided screen of the command prompt. First you get a `302 Found` response to `POST /users/login` afterwards you get redirected to `GET /users/login`.

Anyway, pay attention to the fact that any additional callbacks would not be invoked if authentication failed.

So, most probably, you never reached `console.log` and `res.redirect('/');` because you never got authenticated.

Comment: Yes, but now we always displays the 'Authentication Successful', regardless of whether I was right or not logged...